# How can I use red5 recorder save as not *.flv but ts format?

Tags: save, flv, red5

I record Live Stream With Red5 Media Server successfully.
But the recorded video saved as *.flv, I want it saved as ts format.
How can i get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red5 Media Server always save the stream in the flv formats.If you want to convert the file to any other format ,you can use FFMPEG.Check http://ffmpeg.org/

Hope this will help.Cheers

Comment: Hi Vipin, thanks for your replying. How can I convert *.flv file to *.ts file using FFmpeg In command line? Is there any document? Best Regards,Defonds

Comment: FFMPEG -i (inputfilelocation.flv) (outputfilelocation.ts).This will convert the given flv file to ts format file.Cheers.Type this in command prompt.

Comment: Hi @Defonds : if you have got the result ,then you can accept the answer please.

Comment: Glad you got the answer.Cheers